# How to get Java g.drawString() high resolution?

Tags: java, image, graphics, resolution

I have background templates where java program must write some dynamic texts,

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("background.jpg"));
Graphics g = image.createGraphics();

g.setFont(new Font("DejaVu Sans",Font.PLAIN,18));
g.drawString("Hello,World!",10,10);
```

When writing in such manner, I have some resolution problems around text that Java wrote.

How to write high resolution text on image by Java?

UPDATE: Here example with anti-aliasing.
[image]

```
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Comment: The resolution is determined by the font you use and the number of pixels in the imagine.  Perhaps you are looking for anti-aliasing?

Comment: Thanks, I read articles, then tried, it is not anti-aliasing, background has very resolution, When writing a text by method drawString(), some rectangle with poor number of pixels appears around texts, it looks very bad.

Comment: If you had added a sample image (screenshot), it would have been clearer what you mean.

Comment: @Rinat: It's not at all clear what you mean, please post a screenshot.

Comment: I added image, some blurring around text!

Comment: Yes, these are definitely JPEG artifacts (as Paŭlo noted below). You could either save it as a different type (PNG is perfect for these kinds of images) or try to increase the quality of your JPEG (which might reduce the problem, but probably not remove it entirely).

Comment: Wow! really just changed to png format, and all gone, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the drawing of the text, but the subsequent saving of the file: If you are using JPEG-compression, you will get [compression artifacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact), specially around sharp corners like your text.

There is no real way around this, apart from not using JPG.

Comment: Alternative is to use PNG instead or set the JPEG compression quality to be high. Example snippet to set compression quality is over here: http://www.hide-n-seak.com/hnsnet/snippets/jpegOutput.html